# Grails batch update postgres performance

Tags: json, performance, postgresql, grails

I am trying to do a big one transaction update to postgres database with Grails and json. I have a gzipped json file, i am reading properties from it and updating database accordingly.

Well, i am reading json from a file

```
new FileInputStream("/home/export.gz")
```

passing it on to unzipping stream and creating json parser

```
GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(is)
JsonParser jp = new JsonFactory().createParser(gzipInputStream);
```

parsing json fields...

```
    while (jp.nextToken() != null) {
        if (jp.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            if (jp.nextToken() == JsonToken.FIELD_NAME) {
              ...
            }
        } 
    }
```

Loading each row from database like this

```
private <C> C getById(Class<C> clazz, def id) {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(clazz).setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
    criteria.add(Restrictions.idEq(id))
    return (C) criteria.uniqueResult()
}
```

Got the row, setting fields, flushing each row

```
private void flushAndEvict(def o) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush()
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().evict(o)
    o.discard()
}
```

The problem is that this approach is getting slower by time.
It starts off by updating 500 rows/sec, around 4000 updated the speed is 100 rows/sec and by the time of 30 000 rows updated, the speed is 10 rows/sec, 50 000 updated is around 5 rows/sec.

Monitoring the performance i see that everything is OK with memory, gc spikes do not take more than 5% of the cpu time.

CPU is going full power, 100%, 50% (wall time) sleeping, 42% SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int).

What i am seeing more that socket read/write are going slower, starting with 10 kb/s, 5kb/s at the end of the session.

I am trying to understand what can be the bottleneck here and how to improve performance. What can cause this kind of decrease of speed?

Comment: I don't understand why you are saying that you want to do a big transaction and you are flushing every domain that you save. Are you doing anything transactional?

Comment: @juandiegoh Well data needs to be consistent and i cant to partial update. It's all or nothing.

Comment: as far as I can see you are not doing it transactional, have you tried failling and is doing rollback? Or you have to delete from the database to start again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommend you to do flush every 500 or 1000 (you should check your times and pick one) and after it you should clear your session. With that you won't have any more delays and your time will become linear.

```
def BATCH_SIZE = 1000 // or 500

def myListOfJsonsParsed = [] //...

// ...
def count = 0
myListOfJsonsParsed.each {
    def o = getById(..., it.id)
    // update o fields
    o.save()
    count++
    if(count >= BATCH_SIZE) {
        count = 0
        flushAndClear()
    }
}
flushAndClear()
// ...

private void flushAndClear() {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush()
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear()
}

private <C> C getById(Class<C> clazz, def id) {
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(clazz).setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
    criteria.add(Restrictions.idEq(id))
    return (C) criteria.uniqueResult()
}
```

This won't be a big transaction, this will update every BATCH_SIZE elements, this is the way to do it if your json is really big. On the other hand if you want to do a huge transaction you should not be using flush at all.

```
@Transactional
public void updateDatabase(def myListOfJsonsParsed) {
    myListOfJsonsParsed.each {
        def o = getById(..., it.id)
        o.save()
    }
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend it if **myListOfJsonsParsed** has a lot of elements.

Comment: Yes, btach flush helped. Also i replaced most of the grails' findById methods to get() methods. This way the speed has increased notably. However i still don't really get why speed is slowing down, why isn't it more or less constant.

Comment: The reason is that the hibernate session is being filled all the time without being cleared. This is because with your job you are using just one session so you have to clear it manually. If this were a lot of controller calls, this wouldn't be a problem because grails works with session per request.

Comment: I do this after every batch 
`private flushAndEvictList(List<Object> batch) {
        if(batch.size() > 0) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().flush()
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear()
            for(Object o : batch) {
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().evict(o)
                o.discard()
            }
            batch.clear()
        }
    }`    
Isn't that enough? The memory is not an issue, i've monitored, plenty of it available, gc time less than 5% of thread time.